# How to command RPA Bot to Iterate name in dropdown using workfusion. (RPA)

Tags: automation, rpa, workfusion

I have a employee list which i want to iterate on a site which fetches employee records

[image]

I am using workfusion to automate the manual process but in the first step the user have to select employee name from the dropdown or the user can type the name to filter.

It works if i hard code the name and use keyboard sequence(Typed text) but i have multiple names to iterate and therefore i take a list variable but it fails to select the name from the list variable.

How can I iterate multiple names from the dropdown one by one ?

Answer (score 1):

I am using Workfusion RPA Express and it works perfectly fine iterating lists. Use a 'foreach feature' (or any loop) to iterate on your list. Save the list element to a variable, say list_element. Now, Use 'Enter Keystrokes' feature, change the selection to 'from variable' and choose the variable 'list_element' from dropdown menu in its description.  You can also select option 'typed text' with text as ${list_element}, this works fine too.

Answer (score 0):

is your requirement is to compare drop down values with list of values and select all that apply or just select one particular name.in latter case since you know what exact value need to be selected iterating is not required